# javascript library with easy and comprehensive ajax widget set

Tags: ajax, javascript

I am looking for a javascript library that provides a comprehensive set of widgets that covers most HTML elements and also has a good grid table. The out of the box look and feel must be good. Ajax will be nice as well or else must have ability to attach event handlers.

Any ideas?

PS:
Dont say jQuery please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway jquery is suited for normal needs , i won't personally recommend you any other thing but for the question part you can either go for `Mootools` OR `YUI`

**EDIT**

Go for a look over here

http://javascriptlibraries.com/

Comment: I was thinking of YUI but the download looks a bit big. I would have gone for that but I will affect the download speed of my application significantly. AlloyUI based on YUI is perfect but has the YUI's problems

Comment: YUI has all the features u went for ,specially in handling events!

Comment: absolutely useful link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why not jQuery? It's arguably the best one out there...but anyways, some alternatives are Prototype, MooTools and Dojo...but if you're shying away from jQuery because it's "hard" or some other similar reason, you're not going to have much more luck with any other library out there...all pretty much the same thing...

Comment: jQuery does not have standard widgets.